# Can a window be opened as vbModeless?

Tags: excel, vba, modal-dialog, modeless, vbe

I am using the following code to automate the command bar to unprotect VBE in a locked workbook:

```
Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
```

Next, I add the password to this window using a bunch of code after this and it works fine in another instance of excel but, when used on the same workbook I run into a problem as the code pauses at the point at which the password input window opens.

This seems to be because of the window being opened as Modal so I am now trying to open this as Modeless so that the code continues. Is this even possible?